# Matlab - Generating random numbers and counting

Tags: matlab

I need to create an experiment where I generate random numbers from 1 to 4 and stop when the numbers 1,2,3,4 appear at least once. Then I need to display the amount of random numbers.

I'm new to mathlab and so far I only have a vague idea on how to do this.

I think I need to create a counter for each number and stop when each one is atleast one.

y=randi([1,4]); 
disp(y);
Generates 1 random number but I think I need to use a while loop to keep generating random numbers and break it when the counters are all >=1

Thanks

Comment: i think your idea will work, so what is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to create a counter

Comment: @George: You don't need help generating random numbers. You need to read a basic tutorial on matlab! If you prefer human interaction: Watch a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=matlab+tutorial)

Comment: If you could link me to some tutorials it would be great.

Comment: while 1
 y=randi([1,4]);
 if y == 1
  break
 end
 disp(y);
end

Would display random numbers up to the point when the number is 1. But I dont know how to create a counter and let y>=count...

Answer (score 2):

I think the following code will solve you problem.

```
counter = zeros(4, 1);

while ismember(0, counter)
    y = randi([1, 4]);
    counter(y) = counter(y)+1;
end
```

Counter contains the count for each number.

Comment: How can I repeat this experiment? I know I have to use for a=1:100 end but not sure how to display the sum of each experiment separately

Comment: Just add a for loop outside this code and define a matrix to store the result.

Comment: It displays a 20 by 1 matrix with the same number. How do I change it so each entry is a new experiment?

Comment: You need a100 by 4 matrix, and then each row is an experiment.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. I wanted to change the experiment to having two numbers 0 and 1. And randomly picking one each time. What code would I require to count the longest length of 0's for example  0100110110 would have length 2

Answer (score 0):

Yang Zhang's ^^ is much better

That solution will work! You could also use a vector to store the counters

```
X = zeros(1, 4);
count = 0;
while X(1) == 0 || X(2) == 0 || X(3) == 0 || X(4) == 0
    r = randi([1,4])
    if r == 1
        X(1) = X(1) + 1;
    elseif r == 2
        X(2) = X(2) + 1;
    elseif r == 3
        X(3) = X(3) + 1;
    elseif r == 4
        X(4) = X(4) + 1;
    end
    count = count + 1;
end
disp(count)
```

there is probably a more elegant way to do this, but it is a small enough problem that efficiency is not an big issue